# Run commands as a dead player

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am currently making a gravestone system in minecraft with command blocks, and that means I need to run a command at the location of a player before they die.

I have tried the obvious answer, executing on a player when their deaths score increases: (`deaths` is a scoreboard tracking `deathCount`)

```
execute @e[score_deaths_min=1] ~ ~ ~ summon minecraft:armor_stand
```

however this summons the armor stand after the player respawns because it can't find the player when they are dead

I also tried teleporting a mob to a player when they die, however the mob can't be teleported to a dead player either:

```
summon minecraft:armor_stand 0 1000 0 {CustomName:"deadplayer",NoAI:1b,NoGravity:1b,Invisible:0b,Invulnerable:1b}

tp @e[name=deadplayer] @e[score_deaths=1]
function graves:playerdied unless @e[name=deadplayer,x=0,y=1000,z=0,r=5]
kill @e[name=deadplayer]
```

function **graves:playerdied**:

```
execute @e[name=deadplayer] ~ ~ ~ summon minecraft:armor_stand
```

This does the exact same thing, spawning the armorstand in the player when they click respawn, but not at their death point.

How can I spawn an armorstand or execute commands at the death point of a player, not where they respawn?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@e` cannot target dead players. Only the `@a` selector can (as well as the upcoming `@s` selector, though is irrelevant when you'd need to use `@a` first for `@s` to be functional), and only if the `r/dx/dy/dz` parameters are not specified.

```
execute @a[score_deaths_min=1] ~ ~ ~ summon minecraft:armor_stand
```

Comment: `@s` is no longer upcoming.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `@a` instead, it can detect dead players.

Comment: What does this add to Skylinerw's answer?