# Spawning mobs where a player dies

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

So I'm trying to make a GTA style map and I can't find a command to spawn mobs where a player dies for a police type system... I'm wanting to spawn vindicators with the name Cop but I'm not much for command block knowledge. Any assistance would be helpful

Comment: I recommend reading or watching a commands tutorial first. We expect people here to try things on their own and then asks if they encounter a specific problem with that. See also:[tour]

Comment: I've looked things up I've tried thing but no where have I found something that locates the location of a person's death so then I can spawn mobs there

Comment: Does this help? https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/310589/171580 I think something changed in recent versions about this, so it might be outdated, but that seems to at least be the same question.

Answer (score 0):

Create a scoreboard objective tracking player death count. Every tick summon the vindicator at every **player** with a death count score that's higher than 0, then reset their death count to 0.